# file_get_contents() выдает кракозябры, как поправить?

Tags: php

file_get_contents() выдает кракозябры, как поправить?

```
echo file_get_contents('http://site.com');
```

Comment: Человек, ты не скинул ни примера своего кода, ни структуру проекта (если ты пытаешься читать файл, а не url). Здесь нет экстрасенсов, чтобы понять по 5 словам твою проблему.
Ответ - иди читай мануал php

Comment: Я не экстрасенс, я только учусь, но думаю, что нужно сменить кодировку у полученного контента через iconv()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у получаемой страницы другая кодировка

Посмотрите в какой кодировке приходит страница и попробуйте изменить ее через

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://site.com');
$html = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $response); // CP1251 - просто пример
```

[PHP: iconv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

Comment: Спасибо начинающий экстрасенс, решение подошло!